# apache_beam[gcp] - Sideinput to ParDo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, app-engine-flexible

I could not figure out the right way to add a side input using the ParDo function using apache_beam[gcp] version of 2.4.0.

My pipeline is

```
pipeline
     | "Load" >> ReadFromText("query.txt") 
     | "Count Words" >> CountWordsTransform()

class CountWordsTransform(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, p_collection):
    anotherPipleline = beam.Pipeline(runner="DataflowRunner", argv=[
        "--staging_location", ("%s/staging" % gcs_path),
        "--temp_location", ("%s/temp" % gcs_path),
        "--output", ("%s/output" % gcs_path),
        "--setup_file", "./setup.py"
    ])
       value2 = anotherPipleline | 'create2' >> Create([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)])
       return (p_collection
                | "Split" >> (beam.ParDo(FindWords(), beam.pvalue.AsDict(value2))))
```

The class FindWords() is defined as:

```
class FindWords(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, values):
        import re as regex
        return regex.findall(r"[A-Za-z\']+", element)
```

I receive the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parts'
```

Comment: Error occurs only with apache_beam[gcp] version 2.3.0 and above.No error with beam version 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a separate pipeline inside your composite transform to create your side input - this will cause issues as collections should not be shared across different pipelines.

Instead you could try creating your side input in the same pipeline and passing that as a parameter to your transform.

Eg.

```
values = pipeline | "Get pcol for side input" >> beam.Create([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)])

pipeline 
    | "Load" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://bucket/words.txt')
    | "Count Words" >> CountWordsTransform(values)

class CountWordsTransform(beam.PTransform):

    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    def expand(self, p_collection):
        return p_collection | "Split" >> (beam.ParDo(FindWords(), beam.pvalue.AsDict(self.values)))
```

Tested above with 2.4.0